# Problema de Execução Selenium Python IE 11

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Eu estou com um problema na execução do selenium no IE 11.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Meu código está nessa base, O problema é o seguinte, o navegador abre ai na hora do `send_keys()` ele não acontece nada.

estou usando o seguinte modulo para IEDriverServer.exe, usando `from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager`

Alguém sabe o motivo desse problema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando voce está instanciando a utilização do webdriver, está usando o Firefox e não o IE.

Tente utilizar:

**driver = webdriver.ie()**

ao invés de:

**driver = webdriver.Firefox()**